# Layout in list tile - flutter

Tags: flutter

Current output:

[image]

Expected output:

[image]

Code:

```
SizedBox(
      width: 380,
      height: 180,
      child: Swiper(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      '${items[index].title}',
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      '${items[index].body}',
                    ),
                    trailing: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundColor: HexColor("#0087a8"),
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          );
        },
        viewportFraction: 0.8,
        scale: 0.9,
        control: SwiperControl(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
```

I am unable to create the icon button to be that way. As when i put in padding, it says that the pixels overflowed. I need to get the add button on the bottom right hand side.

Comment: `ListTile` may not be suitable for your expected Layout, You need to try creating custom Widget

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already pointed out, you shouldn't use a `ListTile` for this, as you want to use more than just a title, subtitle for your content.

The reason I've picked a `Stack` over a `Column` here, is that it allows you to safely use it in different size screens whilst assuring the view won't overflow. With `Column`, it would use the button diameter as the whole space to use (vertically), even though it is restrict to the right side of the box.

I believe this is what you're looking for.

[image: example]

```
class MyListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyListTile({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 180.0,
      color: const Color(0xff0087a8),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
          color: const Color.fromRGBO(19, 12, 117, 1.0),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'EUR - USD',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display2.copyWith(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'Forex',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: const Color(0xff0087a8),
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 50.0,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
Container(
        height: 180,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Card(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      'EUR/USD',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 40),
                    ),
                    Text('FOREX', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                        child: IconButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('On Pressed');
                          },
                          icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                        )),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
```

[image: See the image]

Answer (score 1):

Use custom widget for list item OR column from below code for single view. To align left and right you have to put your view in 'Align' as in below -

```
class _ItemsState extends State<Items> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        // TODO: implement build
        return Scaffold(
            body: SizedBox(
                width: 380,
                height: 160,
                child: Card(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: 1,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return

                            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),child:   Column(children: <Widget>[
                              Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    'title',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0 , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,),
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    'body',
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),  )
                                ]),
                              ),
                              Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  child:  CircleAvatar(
                                      maxRadius: 20.0,
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                                      child: IconButton(
                                        icon: Icon(Icons.add,
color: Colors.white,),
                                      ))
                              )
                            ]));




                        }))));
      }
    }
```